# iOS5 Xcode4.2 floating-point byte align error?

Tags: floating-point, ios5, xcode4.2

Look at this code:

this is struct definition file with 1byte struct packing (for socket networking)

```
#pragma pack(1)

typedef struct _TestStruct1 {

double d1;
double d2;

} TestStruct1;


typedef struct _TestStruct2 {

unsigned long v1;
unsigned short v2;
unsigned long v3;
unsigned long value;
TestStruct1 ts1;

} TestStruct2;

#pragma pack()
```

Ok. now see simple code below:

```
TestStruct2 wtf;
wtf.v1 = 0;
wtf.v2 = 0;
wtf.v3 = 0;
wtf.value = 4294967295;
wtf.ts1.d1 = 37.785834f;
wtf.ts1.d2 = 37.785834f;
char * cp = (char *)&wtf;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(TestStruct2); i++) NSLog(@"[%d] %d", i, (int)cp[i]);
NSLog(@"wtf.value: %lu", wtf.value);
```

result on iphone 5.0 simulator XCode 4.2:

```
[0] 0
[1] 0
[2] 0
[3] 0
[4] 0
[5] 0
[6] 0
[7] 0
[8] 0
[9] 0
[10] -1
[11] -1
[12] -1
[13] -1
[14] 0
[15] 0
[16] 0
[17] 64
[18] -106
[19] -28
[20] 66
[21] 64
[22] 0
[23] 0
[24] 0
[25] 64
[26] -106
[27] -28
[28] 66
[29] 64
wtf.value: 4294967295
```

there is no problem. but when it comes to real device (iPhone4)...

```
[0] 0
[1] 0
[2] 0
[3] 0
[4] 0
[5] 0
[6] 0
[7] 0
[8] 0
[9] 0
[10] -1
[11] -1
[12] 0
[13] 0
[14] 0
[15] 64
[16] -106
[17] -28
[18] 66
[19] 64
[20] 0
[21] 0
[22] 0
[23] 64
[24] -106
[25] -28
[26] 66
[27] 64
[28] 88
[29] 84
wtf.value: 65535
```

oh my god what happen? I stored wtf.value with 4294967295, but on the device, it changes to 65535.
this problem happens only on device, not on simulator.

This problem never happens before iOS5 XCode4.2.

How can I fix it? Please help me.

Comment: This appears at first glance to be a bug.  Please file a bug report with Apple.  http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a problem like this, involving floating-point miscalculations but in UI positioning code. I fixed it by adding:

```
-mno-thumb
```

to the "Other C Flags" options under Build Settings, for **armv6** devices only ("Add Build Setting" > "Add Conditional Setting").

I don't pretend to understand exactly what's happening here, but by adding this build setting you're disabling the Thumb instruction set, which according to some (http://wanderingcoder.net/2010/07/19/ought-arm/) is not recommended for armv6 builds anyway. Thumb changes the way floating-point calculations work.

Answer (score 0):

And according to that same person (in reference to Craig's answer), that is, me, [in that very same post](http://wanderingcoder.net/2010/07/19/ought-arm/), handling misaligned data on ARM is very bad (the simulator is x86). I can understand it for integers in network code (though I'd rather explicitly serialize), but there should be no reason to ever have misaligned floating-point numbers (here when you store the floating-point value it seems to be silently realigned to a 4-byte boundary and it overwrites part of wtf.value). You are not transmitting raw floating-point values over the network, right? Right?