# iOS app has changed behaviour after made available on appStore

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, three20

I have created an app targeted for ios 4.1 with base SDK ios 5.0 and tested it with 3G(ios 4.3.3) 3GS(5.1) 3GS(5.0) iPad(5.1). My App has behaved well on all these devices. However, when apple has finaly accepted the app, and i have downloaded it on the same devices, the behaviour has changed.  The problem is that the pages which are displayed are oversized, but if i move them, they properly start fitting the screen. 
Has any of you came across similar situation when the app after publishing changed its behaviour?

And most important. How am i supoosed to reproduce this bug when the same app run from mac on real devices performs excellent?
I may add that base SDK was set to latest(5.0) but app was archived with XCode 4.2 which doesnt support ios 5.1.

Be kind to me, this is my first question :)

EDIT:
After hotpaw's helpful hint, i have checked that the problem was the release build. I can reproduce the bug on the device after changing target in run conf. from debug to release.

What is interesting, and frustrating, I cannot solve the issue, however, I have tested my application  in release mode on xcode 4.3 and it is working perfectly. I have not changed anything, but it works. It can't pack the build( see problem [Xcode 4.3.1 - Packaging operation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664661/xcode-4-3-1-packaging-operation-failed)), so i am stuck with xcode 4.2

For a while i have suspected that the bug is caused by the compiler when compiling for thumb, and the solution would be to add -mno-thumb to other c flags. But i fail to force that flag. See : [iOS5 Xcode4.2 floating-point byte align error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763337/ios5-xcode4-2-floating-point-byte-align-error)

When I compare the compilation log, i can see that xcode 4.3 compiles with -arch armv6 when xcode 4.2 with -arch armv6. But it is the same device which I connect to the computer. I haven't spotted other differences, but they may exist. I can paste the compilation log for sample file if it would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the buggy compiler!

I couldn't notice the difference after applying -mno-thumb to my project, because the library which i used ( Three20) was set to compile only for armv6 which caused the problem and not my project. After adding -mno-thumb to all the projects of Three20 the bug has vanished!

I am going to notice the Three20 team about the issue.

Answer (score 4):

This can happen if you test only Debug Builds, and then submit a Release Build to the App store.  For final test, you need to force Xcode to test with a Release build (perhaps by editing the default schemes), and then submit this build with absolutely no changes to the Build settings, other than code signing.

You might also want to final test your Release build by Ad Hoc installation via iTunes on a freshly reset device from which all previous builds of the app have been deleted. See [Apple's directions for doing this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1764/_index.html).